# Count Odd Numbers below "n" efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a number n, return the number of positive odd numbers below n,

```
oddCount(7) //=> 3, i.e [1, 3, 5]
oddCount(15) //=> 7, i.e [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

My code takes more time to execute for larget counts.
Can anyone suggest a way to make this more time efficient?

```py
def odd_count(n):
    count_odd= [num for num in range(0,n) if num%2!=0]
    count_odd= len(count_odd)
    print(count_odd)
```

Execution Timed Out

STDERR

> **Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)**
>
> Why did my code time out?
>
> Our servers are configured to only allow a certain amount of time for your code to execute. In rare cases, the server may be taking on too much work and simply wasn't able to run your code efficiently enough. Most of the time though this issue is caused by inefficient algorithms. If you see this error multiple times you should try to optimize your code further.

Comment: Please explain why you aren't doing `print(n // 2)`

Comment: You could also do `len(range(1, n, 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm certainly works, but as noted by [cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/cs95) in the comments, all you need is floor division.

```
def count_odds_below(n):
    return n//2
```

This is quicker than your algorithm, and handles large numbers easily.

Example:

```
print(count_odds_below(15))
```

This prints 7.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to count the numbers so you can do:

```
n//2
```

Comment: Why do you need to add `n%2`?

Comment: I thought the number n counts by itself. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

```
function oddCount(n) {
  const newArr = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      newArr.push(i);
    } 
   }
 return newArr.length; }
```

Another option to do the same without execution timeout:

```
function oddCount(n) {
return Math.floor(n/2)}
```